# Monotone maps that can be “extended” to a measure preserving the order

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X\neq\varnothing$ and $\mu:2^X\rightarrow[0,1]$ be a monotone w.r.t. $\subseteq$ map s.t. $\mu(X)=1$, $\mu(\varnothing)=0$, $\mu(Y)=1$ iff $\mu(X\setminus Y)=0$, and for any disjoint $Y$ and $Y'$ s.t. $\mu(Y),\mu(Y')>0$, it holds that $\mu(Y\cup Y')>\mu(U),\mu(Y')$.

Does the following statement hold?

**There is a (finitely or countably additive) probability [measure (in Wiki's sense)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)) $\pi_\mu$ on $2^X$ s.t. $\pi_\mu(Y)\leq\pi_\mu(Y')$ iff $\mu(Y)\leq\mu(Y')$.**

---

If not, is it possible to demand something else from $\mu$ which still will not force it to be a measure?